# Sql server all logins are disabled

Tags: sql-server, authentication

I have the sa login disabled, and I disabled by mistake the other login that is used with windows authentication (named: [server_name]\[computer_name]). Now I can't access the properties of that login to enable it, and I can't run a script to do that...

So now, what is the way to reconnect, should I reinstall sql server? Is there any other way?

I tried this solution: [Connect to SQL Server When System Administrators Are Locked Out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004.aspx) but still unable to login after starting sql server in single-user mode.

Comment: If someone is interested, I solved the problem as follows: 1- Remove only Database Engine Services and all sub elements in the tree using the uninstaller. 2-Run the setup again and choose add features to an existing instance. 3- Choose only the features you removed previously. 4-using the folowing query import your databases: USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [Library] ON 
( FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Library.mdf' )
 FOR ATTACH ;
GO . Done

Comment: Please, add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by uninstalling some features of sql server then reinstall them and restore databases.

These are the steps:
1-Run the uninstaller and remove only Data Base Services and the two items listed under it.
2-Run the setup and choose add features to existing instance and then when you reach the features page choose only those removed in the previous step.
3-Now you have fresh sql server accounts and database engine, but your databases are still there,
by the following query you can restore them one by one:
USE [master] GO CREATE DATABASE [database_name] ON (FILENAME = '...path\dtabase.mdf' FOR ATTACH; GO.